# Discord Game SDK "not_running" result even though it is open

Tags: c++, discord

I was testing the Discord Game SDK to set my activity when i ran into a bit of a problem.

My core was loading just fine, but when it came to set the activity, nothing happened. It seemed like the callback wasn't even triggering. After some breakpoint testing, I found out that the result within the 'RunCallbacks' function was being set to 'DiscordResult_NotRunning" even though my discord client is very much running.

Below you can find my full code. I've hidden the ID's for obvious reasons.

```cpp
#include "SDK/discord.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

void Log(discord::LogLevel level, const char* message) {
    std::cout << "Log(" << (int)level << "): " << message << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    const int switchID = //the application id;
    const int PS5ID = //the application id;
    const int userID = //my discord id;

    discord::Core* core{};
    discord::Result coreResult;

    coreResult = discord::Core::Create(PS5ID, DiscordCreateFlags_Default, &core);
    coreResult == discord::Result::Ok && core
        ? std::cout << "Core Ok\n"
        : std::cout << "Core Not Ok\n";

    core->SetLogHook(discord::LogLevel::Debug, Log);
    core->SetLogHook(discord::LogLevel::Info, Log);
    core->SetLogHook(discord::LogLevel::Warn, Log);
    core->SetLogHook(discord::LogLevel::Error, Log);

    discord::Activity activity = {};
    activity.SetDetails("Details test");
    activity.SetState("");
    activity.GetAssets().SetSmallImage("");
    activity.GetAssets().SetSmallText("");
    activity.GetAssets().SetLargeImage("ps5_logo");
    activity.GetAssets().SetLargeText("PlayStation 5");
    activity.SetType(discord::ActivityType::Playing);

    core->ActivityManager().UpdateActivity(activity, [](discord::Result result) {
        std::cout << "Activity callback begin\n";

        result == discord::Result::Ok
            ? std::cout << "Activity Callback Ok\n"
            : std::cout << "Activity Callback Not Ok\n";
    });

    while (true) {
        core->RunCallbacks();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(16));
    }
}
```

Below are screenshots of the breakpoint testing. 
['RunCallbacks' function code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7D0T.png) and [Result value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJIZN.png)

Can't seem to figure out what's the problem, thanks in advance!

Comment: You should probably mention the version of discord you are running, the version of the SDK and what environments are being used.

Comment: @RodneyP.Barbati Thanks for the advice. 

I'm running the latest version of both.
Discord: Stable 135341 (59d0b47)
GameSDK: Latest version (Unable to specify a version number since it isn't mentioned anywhere in the SDK itself or the website, and it does not have a github either)